# Free sounds for iPhone games

Tags: iphone, audio

I'm looking for a good source for sound effects for my iPhone game.  I like SoundSnap, but they charge you for every sound you download, not just the ones you end up using.  Sound design in games can be a very iterative process and I don't want to pay for 10 sounds I never use before finding the right one.

freesound.org is another really good site, but they are all CC licensed and can't be used in commercial games.  It's unclear if a free iPhone App is considered commercial (or if my final game will be free).

Googling for this returns a huge number of pay sites with horrible web pages.

I don't mind paying for sounds, but I want to pay for what I use.

Any good personal recommendations?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105191/are-there-any-legal-and-royalty-free-sound-libraries-to-get-sounds-for-iphone-ap?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

I personally think that the best source is whatever junk you have at home. I know that you really were looking for a website, but I find that producing your own sounds has big advantages:

-You get to change the sounds little by little to get what you want (online, they're fixed)

-Bashing things in your home inspires creative sound ideas which you didn't think of

-Sometimes a bit faster than searching online for the right keyword

-Free

Don't forget that most professionals in the cinematography industry use slinkies, buckets, sand, and random items to make the perfect sounds which they desire.

You might think that its unfeasible, but with a decent microphone, they come out pretty good. I acknowledge that there are certain sounds which you will not be able to achieve with only the items in your home.